# Find out what instance type an AWS AMI needs

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to launch this ami into AWS: `ami-07b63e4fbc8f71538`.

And I keep getting an error that says:

```
Launch Failed
Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition is not supported for the instance type 't2.large'.
```

The devs who built the application want it to run on the smallest instance possible.

I have tried several sizes of instance and I keep getting the same error. Is there any way to determine what instance type an AMI needs before you launch it?

Comment: I am not sure how you tried, if I try to launch via the `console`, it shows only the instance types which are supported by the AMI, others are greyed out means I can not use them

Answer (score 5):

The SQL Server Enterprise AMIs including [ami-07b63e4fbc8f71538](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Images:visibility=public-images;search=ami-07b63e4fbc8f71538;sort=name) need at least 4 vCPUs, hence t2.large is not compatible.

If you review the Windows with SQL Enterprise documentation at [Amazon EC2 On-Demand Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/), you'll see the list of compatible EC2 instance types.

[image: Windows with SQL Enterprise]

Answer (score 0):

It is a shame it does not cut down the selection automatically as it does for ARM. In fact this seems to be a once only restriction you can take under advisement.

After you have deployed, you can stop the instance and change it to something else with varyng success. But at at least 2 vCores and 7GB unless you are in dev or a sandpit.

And AWS does remember that MSSQL is install (probably from the AMI) so you may have to "wash the AMI". They make it hard.

Also I strongly advise starting with a C3, as you will likely want to resize the root volume. I have the most luck with C3 for this. You can change to a T2 or T3 when that is out of the way.